# NTEContextList key missing from registry in windows 7 / 2008 and newer

Tags: networking, registry, ip-address, tcp, network-interface

I have a code that gets, using remote registry, all IPs configured on a computer.
I'm using the following key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{GUID}\NTEContextList` to determine whether the IPs of the interface are enabled or not.

If the value is 0, I assume the current interface is irrelevant/disabled and doesn't hold a list of ip addresses configured on the computer.
If the value is not 0, I take the ips listed in `IPAddress` value or `DhcpIPAddress` value (depending on `DhcpEnabled` value.

The problem I'm facing is that on computers having Windows 7 / Server 2008 and newer, this key is missing.
Do you have any idea where it's hidden / what other key can I use to determine whether the IPs of the interface are relevant or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has this question - you can use WMI query for NICs with NetEnabled == True starting with Vista/2008 - don't forget that Admin credentials needed:

```
    $enabledNICs = @()
        try 
        {
            $enabledNICs = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential -Filter "netenabled=true" 
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error "The computer $ComputerName is not accessible for WMI query"
            continue
        }
```